# Simplifying Expression $\sum\limits_{x=1}^{k} {N - x \choose k - x} x^2$

Tags: combinatorics

Simplifying expression $$\sum_{x=1}^{k} {N - x \choose k - x} x^2$$ where we assume $N > k$. According to my professor, this is unable to be simplified by hand (simplified meaning no summation notation, closed form, explicit expression). Plugging into Wolfram Alpha yields $$\frac{-N(N+1)(k+N+1)}{(k-N-3)(k-N-2)(k-N-1)}\binom{N-1}{k-1}$$ Are there any insights that can be made to reach this expression by hand? Thanks

Comment: Note that you can bring your Wolfram|Alpha result into the form given in the answers linked to above by including the factors $N(N+1)$ and $(k-N-3)(k-N-2)(k-N-1)$ in the binomial coefficient:

$$
\binom{N-1}{k-1}=\binom{N-1}{N-k}
$$

and

$$
\binom{N-1}{N-k}\frac{N(N+1)}{(N-k+1)(N-k+2)(N-k+3)}=\frac1{k-1}\binom{N+1}{N-k+3}=\frac1{k-1}\binom{N+1}{k-2}\;.
$$